# Fetching timestamps (hh:mm:ss) from Youtube comments with Youtube API using regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube-api

I am analyzing timestamped YouTube comments. Because some comments may refer to a period in either mm:ss, m:ss, hh:mm:ss, or h:mm:ss, I need to prepare for these cases. The following code works on mm:ss and m:ss, but still treats the one with hours as if it was mm:ss. For example, 02:24:30 returns 144, as it is only analyzing the first two parts. Here is the code:

```
var timePattern = /(([0-5][0-9])|[0-9])\:[0-9]{2,2}/;
var seconds = "";

for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
    var matches = comments[i].match(timePattern);
    var matched = matches[0];
    var a = matched.split(':');
    if(matched.length == 7 || matched.length == 8) {
        seconds = (+a[0])*60*60 + (+a[1])*60 + a[2];        
    } else {
        seconds = (+a[0])*60 + (+a[1]); 
    }
    times.push(seconds);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/). Read more write less.

Comment: Well I'm using the YouTube API for plenty of things with this particular project, but I don't think there's anything there that will get me comments with time references in them (ex. "LOL 3:04!!!") and certainly not anything that will break that reference into seconds for me.

Comment: Actually, this is possible, look at the `entry` elements: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Comments

Comment: Yes, you can get comments. You just can't retrieve the video time references in those comments with the API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try a different regex.

```
(?:([0-5]?[0-9]):)?([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])
```

First contains hours, second contains minutes, last contains seconds.

Hours will be empty if no hours are found.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! I'll select this answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this info on the comments feed, if you're using the API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Comments

The comments feed have a `published` element that contains the date and time information that you can use to parse the seconds of.

Comment: I think he means the references to certain times in the video itself, not when the comment was posted. Example: "lol @ 0:24, nose picking"

Comment: I'm not looking for the time the comment was published. The `comments` array is filtered to leave comments that refer to a time in the video in mm:ss format. What I'm trying to do is take the first occurrence of one of these references in each comment and convert THAT to seconds. ohaal's answer is what I was looking for, but I really appreciate your input.

Comment: Oh... I see now. Sorry. Anyway, I think my answer fits someone elses doubts, so I'll not delete it.

Comment: Yeah, it will likely answer someone's question sometime down the line. @ohaal, perfect example of a YouTube comment :)